# DisplayIndex reading incorrectly when rows hidden

Tags: c#, wpf

The goal is to copy the selected cell data out of a selected row.

I'm doing this by catching the CopyingRowClipBoardContent event inside my datagrid and redirecting it to this code:

```
var currentCell = e.ClipboardRowContent[VwrGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex];
e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();
e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(currentCell);
```

This works perfectly! the only issue, is that if some of the columns are hidden, DisplayIndex reads improperly.

So if we have Item 1, Item 2, and Item 3.

If all are showing and I selected item3 and copy it, I get the cell value in Item 3.

The problem is, If Item 2 is collapsed/not shown, then copying Item 3 will tell you you're trying to copy out of bounds. because it's counted displayIndex , 3 from the left, and only two were shown. so it's moved outside of the table

[image: No such field as index]

Answer (score 3):

For WPF Datagrid, try this:

```
// The clipboard row works only for visible cells
// To obtain the data column use the columnIndex and then map that to the Columns collection
int columnIndex = dataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
var column = dataGrid.Columns[columnIndex];

// Now get the needed column 
var cellContent = e.ClipboardRowContent.Where(i => i.Column == column).First();
e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();
e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(cellContent);
```

For Winforms:

Use `.Index` instead. `.DisplayIndex` applies only to *visible* columns.

Comment: No such field! that would have been a nice fix though

Comment: There is such a field for the DataViewGridColumn class. May I ask what class type if *VwrGrid* in your code sample???

Comment: it's a WPF DataGrid

Comment: It's a DataGridColumn, not a DataViewGridColumn

Comment: I totally missed that this was WPF. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is WPF and I can't simply use an index, I just iterated through the columns and counter the number of columns that had their visibility set to collapsed up to the column we were attempting to grab the displayindex for. Then subtracted that number from the displayIndex.

```
private void DataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    //because we need to use displayindex, we need to check how many collapsed columns there are before our column, and adjust our display index accordingly
    int invisibleCols = 0;
    foreach(DataGridColumn col in VwrGrid.Columns)
    {
        if (col.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            invisibleCols++;

        if (col.Header.ToString() == VwrGrid.CurrentCell.Column.Header.ToString()) break;
    }
    try
    {
        var currentCell = e.ClipboardRowContent[VwrGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex - invisibleCols];
        e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();
        e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(currentCell);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```